# How to generate all strings with d-mismatches, python

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I have a following string - "AACCGGTTT" (alphabet is ["A","G","C","T"]). I would like to generate all strings that differ from the original in any two positions i.e.

```
GAGCGGTTT
^ ^ 
TATCGGTTT
^ ^
```

How can I do it in Python?

I have only brute force solution (it is working):

1. generate all strings on a given alphabet with the same length
2. append strings that have 2 mismatches with a given string

However, could you suggest more efficient way to do so?

Comment: your "alphabet" is wrong, the four base pairs are AGCT.

Comment: Have you attempted a solution yet? Please show the code you currently have, and we can help with that. Otherwise, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [introducing mutations in a DNA string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679855/introducing-mutations-in-a-dna-string-in-python)

Comment: I thought this question sounded a little familiar.. looks like I was [right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679855/introducing-mutations-in-a-dna-string-in-python)..

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go with using itertools.  Maybe something like

```
from itertools import combinations, product

def generate(s, d=2):
    N = len(s)
    letters = 'ACGT'
    pool = list(s)

    for indices in combinations(range(N), d):
        for replacements in product(letters, repeat=d):
            skip = False
            for i, a in zip(indices, replacements):
                if pool[i] == a: skip = True
            if skip: continue

            keys = dict(zip(indices, replacements))
            yield ''.join([pool[i] if i not in indices else keys[i] 
                           for i in range(N)])
```

Then just

```
list(generate("AACCGGTTT"))
```